# How to get text value from GText.view?

Tags: gtk, ocaml, lablgtk

I am creating a GUI in OCaml using Lablgtk. I have created a text view like so:

```
let textView = GText.view ~border_width:2
            ~packing:vbox#add () in
            textView#buffer#set_text "Hello World";
```

Later I want to take the text in the text view and pass it to a function. However I can't figure out how to do this and documentation seems to be very scarce. How can I do this? Better yet, is there a tutorial or any thorough documentation for the various objects and their properties available in Lablgtk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that [GText.buffer](http://oandrieu.nerim.net/ocaml/lablgtk/doc/GText.buffer.html) has a get_text method which can be used like so:

```
let text = textView#buffer#get_text () in
```